# Array sem repetição

Tags: java, array

Como fazer para não repetir os dados a cada execução?

Cada vez que eu Executo, ele acaba repetindo as datas no momento da execução, como Eu faço para Ele sortear as datas sem repeti-las, e quando acabar a quantidade de datas disponiveis nesta collection ele exiba uma mensagem de que acabaram-se as opções?

```
package DeclaracaoArray;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Declaracao_Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Declaracao_Array d = new Declaracao_Array();
        System.out.println(d.data());
    }

    public String data (){
        List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();


        lista.add ( "01/09/2015" );
        lista.add ( "02/09/2015" );
        lista.add ( "03/09/2015");
        lista.add ( "04/09/2015");
        lista.add ( "08/09/2015" );
        lista.add ( "09/09/2015" );
        lista.add ( "10/09/2015");
        lista.add ( "11/09/2015");
        lista.add ( "14/09/2015" );
        lista.add ( "15/09/2015" );
        lista.add ( "17/09/2015");
        lista.add ( "18/09/2015");
        lista.add ( "21/09/2015" );
        lista.add ( "22/09/2015" );
        lista.add ( "23/09/2015");


        Collections.shuffle ( lista );


        return lista.get(0);

    }

}
```

Comment: O que você quer dizer com `não repetir os dados a cada execução`?

Comment: Não repetir os dados de uma nova lista ?

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta, ficou vago...Me desculpem.

Comment: O `shuffle()` não está embaralhando?

Comment: @jsantos1991 deu certo, coloque como resposta que Eu votarei nela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se pretende que não haja repetições, antes de devolver o valor remova da lista:

```
package DeclaracaoArray;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Declaracao_Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Declaracao_Array d = new Declaracao_Array();
        System.out.println(d.data());
    }

    public String data (){
        List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();


        lista.add ( "01/09/2015" );
        lista.add ( "02/09/2015" );
        //...
        lista.add ( "23/09/2015");

        //verifique se já não está vazia
        if(lista.isEmpty()) return "Opções esgotadas.";
        else{
            Collections.shuffle ( lista );
            String aux = lista.get(0);
            lista.remove(0);
            return aux;
        }    
    }

}
```